# A bootstrap table not as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to draw a simple two-columns table exactly as the one in the Bootstrap page: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables.
[image: What is desired]
For that I am using a javascript to render it as you can see here:

```
                 $(\"#rep\").empty()
                 $(\"#rep\").append("<br><br><table class=\\"table table-bordered table-striped\\"><tr><th><strong>Title</strong></th><th><strong>Description</strong></th></tr>")
                 //for (var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) { 
                 for (var key in ratings){
                        var table = "";
                        table = "<tr> <th scope=\\"row\\"><code>"
                        table += key
                        table += "</code></th> <td>"
                        table += ratings[key]
                        table += "</td></tr>"
                        $(\"#rep\").append(table);
                    }
                 $(\"#rep\").append("</table>")
        }, "json")
```

The problem is that I don't get the same, and I obtaine a table with the two columns' titles not aligned with the other rows. Like you can see here:
[image: What I obtain]

Does anyone know what could be the problem ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: it would be helpful to either see the rendered code, or better yet if you could create a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code :

1) You are not using `<colgroup>` as the bootstrap example. Thats why the table not is aligned properly.

2) You are not using `<thead>` or `<tbody>` at all, thats another reason why the table not is aligned properly, and the reason why your `.table-striped` table not is striped. The CSS for striping the rows is

```css
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

Having said this, why are you regenerating the entire table from scratch? I would empty `<tbody>` only :

```js
$("#rep table tbody").empty();
```

and then just append new rows, like this :

```js
var tr = 
  '<tr>'+
     '<th scope="row">'+
        '<code>'+key+'</code>'+
      '</th>'+
      '<td>'+ratings[key]+'</td>'+
   '</tr>';
   $("#rep table tbody").append(tr);
```

here is a demonstration -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j11mj21x/**